# Is this function Lipschitz in two dimensions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I want to show that the function $A(x,y)$ is Lipschitz in two dimensions. 
The function is defined as follows

$$A(x,y)=a\frac{\Phi(y)\Phi(-y)e^{0.5(y^2-x^2)}+\Phi(x)\Phi(-x)e^{0.5(x^2-y^2)}}{1+a(1-2\Phi(x))(1-2\Phi(y))}$$

where $a\in[-1,1]$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function.
How can I show this is Lipschitz?

Could anyone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try for first to prove the following inequality:
$$\frac{1}{4+x^2}e^{-x^2/2} \leq\Phi(x)\Phi(-x)\leq \frac{1}{4}e^{-x^2/2}.\tag{1} $$
If we set $B(x,y)=1+a(1-2\Phi(x))(1-2\Phi(y))$ then $(1)$ implies:
$$ \frac{(4+x^2)e^{-x^2/2}+(4+y^2)e^{-y^2/2}}{(4+x^2)(4+y^2)\,B(x,y)}\leq\frac{A(x,y)}{a}\leq \frac{e^{-x^2/2}+e^{-y^2/2}}{4\,B(x,y)}\tag{2}$$
hence $A(x,y)$, as a product of two bounded (if $a^2\neq 1$) Lipshitz functions, is a bounded Lipschitz function. Graphically, when $a$ is extremely close to $1$, this is the behaviour of $e^{-x^2/2}+e^{-y^2/2}$:

[image: Behaviour of N]

(very regular), while this is the behaviour of $\frac{1}{B(x,y)}$:

[image: Behaviour of B]

(a smooth-step function) so their product behaves like the smoothed indicator function of a two-dimensional set:

[image: Behaviour of BN]