# Is this a Lipschitz function in 2d?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I want to show that the function $A(x,y)$ is Lipschitz in two dimensions. 
The function is defined as follows

$$A(x,y)=a\frac{\Phi(-y)e^{0.5(y^2-x^2)}+\Phi(-x)e^{0.5(x^2-y^2)}}{(1-a)[1-a(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y))]+2a\Phi(x)\Phi(y)}$$

where $a\in[-1,1]$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function.
How can I show this is Lipschitz?

Could anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to apply techniques from your other similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888227/is-this-function-lipschitz-in-two-dimensions. Can you prove that your function is a product of two bounded Lipschitz functions?

Comment: You may be even interested to this inequality: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888726/an-interesting-inequality-about-the-cdf-of-the-normal-distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888227/is-this-function-lipschitz-in-two-dimensions) had products like $\Phi(y)\Phi(-y)$, which provide rapid decay in both positive and negative directions.

But here you have things like $\Phi(-y)e^{0.5(y^2-x^2)}$, where $\Phi(-y)\to 1$ as $y\to-\infty$. The exponential factor grows rapidly as $y\to -\infty$.

Let's put $x=0$ and let $y\to -\infty$. Then

$$(1-a)[1-a(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y))]+2a\Phi(x)\Phi(y) \to (1-a)(1-a/2) $$

and

$$\Phi(-x)e^{0.5(x^2-y^2)}\to 0,$$

so $A(x,y)$ is asymptotic to $\dfrac{a}{ (1-a)(1-a/2)} e^{0.5(y^2-x^2)}$.

Comment: So the answer is basically that it's not a Lipzchitz function?